# Properties of the filtered preference list (phase 1) in the Stable Roommates problem

Tags: algorithms, matching

I'm currently working my way through [An Efficient Algorithm for the “Stable Roommates” Problem](https://uvacs2102.github.io/docs/roomates.pdf) by Robert Irving (*Journal of Algorithms*, 6:577–595, 1984).

On page 7 the paper starts with describing the algorithm for phase 2. The only thing that phase two does is reducing all-or-nothing cycles.  The paper seems to assume that after phase 1, the proposal and filter phase, the filtered preference lists can be divided into three categories:

1. One or more of the filtered preference lists is empty. Therefore no stable roommate assignment exists.
2. Each filtered preference list contains only one element. Therefore a stable roommate assignment exists.
3. The filtered preference list contains an all-or-nothing cycle (wikipedia calls this rotations).

But why can't you have filtered preference lists that contain more than one element but does not contain an all-or-nothing cycle.

Comment: @Henk Thanks for clarifying. It's best to make such clarifications a part of the question itself, so people don't have to read the comments to figure out what's going on. I took the liberty of doing that (and adding a full citation to the paper you're asking about) but please check I didn't mess anything up! Welcome to the site!